# trouble parsing my mat4 transformation matrix into my opengl shader?

Tags: c++, parsing, opengl, matrix, transformation

The error messages I am getting are:

```
ERROR: 0:5: error<#12>> Unexpected qualifier
ERROR: 0:5: error<#12> Syntax error: "in_transformation" parse error
ERROR: error<#273> 2 compilation errors. No code generated
```

This is my drawing function in which i parse the transformation matrix into the shader. I am not certain this should be here, should this be in the initialization function where i parse in the vertex array? matrices?

```
    void Mesh3D::Draw()
    {
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        // Draw elements of each mesh in the vector
        glm::mat4 matrix = matrixViewProjection*this->matrixModel;
        int loc = glGetUniformLocation(program, "in_transformation");
        glUniformMatrix4fv(loc, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(matrix));
        for (int i = 0; i<nVectorGeometry; i++)
        {
            glBindVertexArray(vaos[i]);
            glDrawElements(col->vectorGeometry[i].primitive
            col->vectorGeometry[i].index_count,
            GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, col->vectorGeometry[i].indices);
        }
        glBindVertexArray(0);
        glutSwapBuffers();
    }
```

This is my vertex shader as I store it in a header file
NOTE it all worked without me parsing in the transformation matrix so the problem is not related to how i store the shader

```
static std::string  shaderVert = "#version 330\n"
"in vec3 in_coords;\n"
"in vec3 in_normals;\n"
"in vec4 in_colors; \n"//added by me
"in map4 in_transformation;\n"//added by me
"out vec3 vertex_normal;\n"
"out vec4 vertex_color;\n"
"void main(void) {\n"
"vertex_normal = in_normals;\n"
"vertex_color = in_colors;\n"//added by me
"gl_Position =in_transformation* vec4(in_coords, 1.0);\n"
"}\n";
```

Thanks, I am not sure if I am setting up the transformation matrix right :/?

This is the format of my transformation matrix:

```
static glm::mat4 matrix =
{ 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f };
```

Answer (score 1):

Your transformation variable is not a "uniform" variable in the shader. Also it's of the type map4, are you sure you didn't mean mat4?

You may want to declare it as

```
uniform mat4 transformation;
```

And then you can get the location and parse it.

Also, consider reading your shaders from a file so you don't have to add newlines at the end of every line explicitly. I know it works that way, but it's easier for you to write your shaders.

Comment: thanks man its working now. I make the most ridiculous mistakes sometimes!. I like to put as much into the application as i can. If i had it my way everything would be in a single exe file!